# Uniform random number generated was repeated

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random

I was trying to generate 100 uniform random variable from 0.0 to 1.0. 
I used the time based seed to generate it but the number generated seems repeated a few before changing to another one. Was there any better way to simualte without repeating?

Output was like:
0.33456, 0.33456, 0.33456, 0.11256, 0.11256, 0.11256, 0.94092, 0.94092, ...

```
Real UniformDistributionGenerator(double range_from, double range_to) {
    Real uniform_r_v = 0.0;
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 generator(seed);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(range_from, range_to);
    uniform_r_v = distribution(generator);
    return uniform_r_v;
}
```

Comment: You're reseeding a deterministic RNG with the same clock value (`time_since_epoch` only has millisecond resolution). You should be persisting the RNG state *outside* of your `UniformDistributionGenerator` function. Also consider using a [better random number generator](http://www.pcg-random.org/), and a better seed than time-in-milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:    `static std::mt19937 generator(seed);`
Seeded once per program run, as it should be.